# Meaning of "Last time I checked..."

Tags: pronunciation, listening

I've been learning English with movie trailers.
I can't understand what he said in "Hitman: Agent 47" at 0:43.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=U2VDZsUoAXk#t=42

Before the subtitle "You're the one locked in here with me and I'm the one with the gun", I think that the detective said "Last time I checked" but I can't understand that.

Please teach me what he really said and the meaning.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree wholeheartedly with J.R.'s answer.  I just wanted to explain in more detail the literal meaning of "Last time I checked".

Let's say I lock the door at 1:00.  An hour later, it's now 2:00. I'm not sure if the door is still locked. Maybe someone used a key to unlock it.  Maybe someone picked the lock and broke in illegally. I don't know. So I check the door and see it is still locked. An hour later at 3:00 I check again and it is still locked.  At 3:30 someone asks me "Is the door locked?" I can say, "The last time I checked it was locked, but it's been 30 minutes since I last checked, so I can't be sure if it's still locked now.". In fact I would just say "Last time I checked." That would be a literal non-sarcastic use of the phrase.

A sarcastic use would be if someone asked me "Are you male?" I might answer jokingly, "Last time I checked."  This implies that I check my gender from time to time, and that the last time I checked I was male, but I concede the possibility that my gender might have changed without my knowledge since the last time I checked. Of course that's ridiculous. What I'm really saying is the opposite: I am absolutely certain of my gender.

In the movie trailer, the conversation goes like this:

Man #1:  You should let me go.  (Meaning, you are not in control of this situation.)

Man #2: Last time I checked, I'm the one with the gun. (Meaning, I am absolutely certain I am in control. This is the opposite of the literal meaning. A small joke.)

Man #1 escapes, thus demonstrating that Man #2 is not in control. (A bigger joke.)

In the end, to a native speaker, the phrase means "I am certain this is true, and to emphasize that I am absolutely certain, I am willing to joke that perhaps I am not certain, that perhaps the situation has changed since the last time I checked, even though I truly believe it cannot have changed."

Answer (score 17):

Yes, the character says, "Last time I checked."

It's a stock phrase that means, essentially: "If I remember correctly..."

It's usually said with a least a moderate bit of sarcasm. For example, if someone new at work asked me:

> What time does our lunch break start?

I would **not** say:

> Last time I checked, lunch starts at noon.

However, if a co-worker was leaving a little early, and I wanted to give him a hard time about it (perhaps good-naturedly), I might say:

> Last time I checked, lunch starts at noon.

This would be about the same as saying:

> You're leaving for lunch a little early today, aren't you?

<sub>One more thing (not to make it a little more complicated, but this is how the phrase is used!)</sub>

The phrase can also be used *literally*. So, let's say that the new coworker asked me:

> What time does our lunch break start?

I might say something like this:

> Last time I checked, lunch starts at noon.

Without the sarcasm, that means: "The last time I looked at company regulations, they said our lunch starts at noon – but that was awhile ago, and the rules may have changed since then."

In the movie clip, though, I'm pretty sure it's the sarcastic flavor of the expression being used.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth explanation. It makes me understand that phrase clearly. Really thanks.

Comment: @Go - Not a problem. Last time I checked, we were here to be helpful. (So, you see, you can even use the expression in a positive way, too. It's often humor-laced – but not always in a negative way.)